# Django Schedule Appointment Form Issue

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I am creating a form where a user can click a time slot and reserve that time slot. There are 5 columns, one for each day of the week (mon, tues, wed, etc..) with 5 rows of times slots (3pm, 4pm, 5pm, 6pm, 7pm).

Each time slot represents a radio input checkbox choice. The example below only has 2 columns.

How could I seperate radio input buttons 1-6 and 7-12 into two different  blocks.

**Forms.py**

```
class AppointmentForm(forms.Form):
One = 1
Two = 2
Three = 3
Four = 4
Five = 5
Six = 6
SEVEN = 7
EIGHT = 8
NINE = 9
TEN = 10
ELEVEN = 11
TWELVE = 12
TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (One, '3:00pm'),
    (Two, '3:45pm'),
    (Three, '4:30pm'),
    (Four, '5:15pm'),
    (Five, '6:00pm'),
    (Six, '6:45pm'),
    (SEVEN, '3:00pm'),
    (EIGHT, '3:45pm'),
    (NINE, '4:30pm'),
    (TEN, '5:15pm'),
    (ELEVEN, '6:00pm'),
    (TWELVE, '6:45pm')

)
appointment_time = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=TYPE_CHOICES,
        label="Appointment times",
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        required=True,
         )
```

**AppointmentForm.html**

```
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|crispy }}
  <label for="id_id_appointment_time_0_1" class="form-check-label">1:00pm</label>
  <input class="btn btn-success-alt " type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Attempting to create this**
[image: I am trying to create the this]

**This is where I am at**
[image: This is what I have]

Comment: You're looking for crispy formhelpers and their [layout](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html).

Comment: The problem I see, is that I need to break a single field, which has 12 input fields (radio selects) into separate divs. The single field will have multiple inputs.